# How to remove round tiles easily from a plate

Tags: disassembly

I have made a road  for a medieval style MOC by putting [1x1 tile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3070b#T=C&C=86), [1x1 round tile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138#T=C&C=86) and [1x1 round plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4073#T=C&C=11) on plates of varying sizes.

[image: square tile] [image: round tile] [image: round plate]

When I want to remove the round tile from a stud not on any outer edges of a plate, I'm having a very hard time doing so. When trying to use a brick separator for it, I sometimes even damage the brick separator instead of removing the round tile. Does anyone have any tricks how to remove round tiles easily from a plate?

Edit: I'm trying to find a way to remove the round tiles from a plate when the round tile is not located on any stud on any of the sides of the plate. For the square tile I'm able to do so with my finger nails and the round plate is easy with a brick separator. Unfortunately I haven't yet found any good way of doing this to a round tile and it has no studs to attach a brick separator to and no corners to put your finger nails under. I have created a simple drawing to illustrate what I want to do. I'm looking for a way to remove a round plate from any of the studs marked in red on my drawing and doing so without damaging myself or any of the parts.

[image: Diagram of a plate and round tiles]

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding your issue - you are trying to remove tiles by utilizing anything but a groove? Why?

Comment: Oh, and brick separator is made of softer plastic and is supposed to be damaged first, in case of using too much force, before any LEGO elements take damage.

Comment: I have edited my question to hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some searching on other lego related sites on the internet I found the useful suggestion to use a brick separator upside down. I have tested this and it is indeed much easier to do it this way if you have enough space to do so. [image: Brick separator used upside down]

Answer (score 6):

Modern tiles have grooves at the very bottom, which were designed specifically for the ease of removal. Here is an example how you can remove tiles from inside the plate (taken from one of recent mosaic set's instruction):

[image]

Even though picture shows variation of classic orange, which is narrower than pictured above, same technique applies to both.

LEGO has even got a [dedicated webpage](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/brickseparator/classic) for Classic Brick Separator (wide, black version is called "Art" and has its own page as well). It contains example seen below. Although, I have never experienced parts flying like that during such disassembly.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In addition to brick separators, recent Art sets have come with a [crowbar piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=92585&idColor=115), apparently intended to make removal of individual circular tiles easier:

[image: Image of pearl gold crowbar piece from an official photo of the 31202 Mickey Mouse Art set]

I haven't tried it myself, but it should be easier to maneuver between pieces than a whole brick separator.

Answer (score 3):

I have kits for repair work on electronics, and have used the spudgers and plastic pry bars for Legos in tight spots. The kits are usually pretty cheap. Here’s an example: https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Tools/Prying-and-Opening-Tool-Assortment/IF145-364?o=1

I like them because they’re durable but usually softer than anything I might use them on (so they don’t mar).